# How to mock a job in Pester?

Tags: powershell, mocking, pester

We're trying to assess if `Invoke-Command` has been called exactly one time.

**Script.ps1**

```
$job = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {'test'} -ComputerName localhost -AsJob 
$job | Wait-Job
```

**Script.Tests.ps1**

```
BeforeAll {
    $testScript = $PSCommandPath.Replace('.Tests.ps1', '.ps1')
    Mock Invoke-Command
}
Describe 'Test' {
    It 'should be green' {
        . $testScript
        Should -Invoke Invoke-Command -Times 1 -Exactly -Scope It
    }
}
```

The problem is mocking the job object in Pester. When the job is not mocked, `Wait-Job` will throw an error that it didn't receive a job object.

How is it possible to mock a PowerShell job object in `Pester`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution might be to have the `Mock` of Invoke-Command still create a legitimate job, but executing some script/code that you deem safe for the purpose of testing.

To do this, you need to first put the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet in a variable so that you can use it via that variable (because a `Mock` can't directly call its own command).

For example:

```
$InvokeCommand = Get-Command Invoke-Command

Mock Invoke-Command {
     & $InvokeCommand -ScriptBlock {'some safe alternative code'} -ComputerName localhost -AsJob
}
```

Comment: This is Nice. Neat and clean approach.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Like you said, it kept calling its own `Mock`. Love your solution! Big thumbs up Mark :)

Comment: Excellent solution.